# How do I make buttons that disable/enable eachother when pressed in JS + HTML?

Tags: javascript, html

I am trying to make a compound interest calculator (I'm starting out in JS) and I'm trying to make buttons that enable the other one, and disable itself when pressed.

```js
function select_button(button) {
    var buttonId= button.id;
    
    if(buttonId="Deposit") {
        document.getElementById("Withdraw").disabled = false;
        document.getElementById("Deposit").disabled = true;
    }
    if(buttonId="Withdraw") {
        document.getElementById("Withdraw").disabled = true;
        document.getElementById("Deposit").disabled = false;
    }
};
```

```html
<button id="Deposit" disabled=true type="button" onclick="select_button(Deposit);"> Deposit </button> <button id="Withdraw" type="button" onclick="select_button(Withdraw);">Withdraw</button>
```

This is my current code. For some reason, when I press on Withdraw, it functions as intended. But when I press on Deposit, it disables Withdraw and enables itself.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`=` is the assignment operator, you want to use at least `==` but preferably `===` when comparing things in JavaScript.

What you want to do is:

```
function select_button(button) {
    var buttonId= button.id;
    
    if(buttonId === "Deposit") {
        document.getElementById("Withdraw").disabled = false;
        document.getElementById("Deposit").disabled = true;
    }
    if(buttonId === "Withdraw") {
        document.getElementById("Withdraw").disabled = true;
        document.getElementById("Deposit").disabled = false;
    }
};
```

Comment: Could have been a comment and closed based on typo..

Comment: not sure what that means, but I'm sorry I offended you

Comment: That worked! What is the difference between "==" and "==="?

Comment: You didn't offend me. I'm pointing out that this answer could have been a comment instead of this answer. Also, because this was caused by a typo, people in the future won't find this helpfull, so it should be closed based on this reason.

Comment: ==  checks for loose equality while === checks for strict equality, you might want to read up more on it. Basically 1 == "1" will be true while 1 === "1" won't be.

Comment: It was not a typo. I did not know you had to use "==" / "===" instead of "=".

Comment: Although this question will not be very useful in the future for the community, it was of great help to the questioner, since for x or y reason they did not recognize the failure

Answer (score 1):

You should change your equal symbol `=` working as the assignment operator to conditional operator, you can use `==` or `===`

I.E.
`buttonId="Deposit"` to `buttonId === "Deposit"`